# Add more tooltips in the "Admin Summary" page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Some of the headers for the table shown in the "Admin Summary" page have a tooltip, but there are headers without a tooltip, or without a tooltip that explains exactly its meaning.

[image: screenshot]

- Cmnts deleted: Does this field include the comments created from the moderator, and then deleted? Does it include the comments deleted when deleting a post?
- Post deleted: Does this include the posts created from the moderator?
- Post closed: Does this include the questions asked from the moderator? Are questions the moderator created, and that could have been deleted if the OP was not a moderator included (i.e. a question without up-voted answers)?
- Meta Posts: What are the numbers shown in that column?

The "Meta Posts" header has a tooltip, but it doesn't say much, compared with the one for the "Cmnts deleted" header.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As a side note, some of the tooltips like on comments created just repeat the number you're hovering over. Useless!

Comment: @BenBrocka Yeah, tooltips on numbers should totally spell out the number in words: `two hundred` or `six thousand, seven hundred and ninety-two`

Comment: @TheEstablishment no, they should spell the number out in *braille*. That's how accessibility works, right?